# SQL Server 2008 R2: Display specific row without using WHERE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table with three column's as shown below:

Table:

```
create table empo
(
    employeeID int,
    employeeName varchar(10),
    employeeSalary int
);
```

Insert:

```
insert into empo values(1, 'A', 1000);
insert into empo values(2, 'B', 16000);
insert into empo values(4, 'C', 51000);
insert into empo values(3, 'D', 31000);
insert into empo values(5, 'E', 4000);
```

**Note**: Now I want to display 3rd record only which is `4,'C',51000` without using any values of that record in the condition.

My attempt:

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY employeeID ASC) rn
     from empo) result
where 
   result.rn = 3;
```

But I'm getting a wrong result:

```
employeeID  employeeName    employeeSalary
-------------------------------------------
    3           D               31000
```

Comment: there's no way to get your result without a column that specifies the inserting order

Comment: There is **no** inherent order to tables. There's no "third row" without specifying one or more columns to *define* an order.

Comment: Is it allowed to add a field to the table to force order?

Comment: @TT you can't force order by adding a field. You need an ORDER BY clause to do that. You *can* force order with a clustered index but there's no guarantee the results will come in any order after applying any operators

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you can if the added field is an IDENTITY field.   Though by "force order" I mean have a column that can be used to order queries by the order in which the rows were inserted.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, So how can i get that result? If not possible with row_number() function.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - no, a clustered index still doesn't guarantee row order. Just as one example, SQL Server can make use of a table-scan already in progress for another query, return results from that, and then start another table-scan to complete gathering results

Comment: @TabAlleman no, it doesn't affect ordering. IDENTITY only provides an auto-generated value. You probably confuse it because it's typically used on Primary Keys

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I did mention that - apply any operator and there is no guarantee

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - that's not applying *any* operators. That's `SELECT * FROM Table` when *another* query (on another connection) is already running a table scan on `Table`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever sorry, was thinking in terms of execution plans. In fact, even a single query can return unordered if the optimizer decides to parallelize it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I implied no such thing. Just asking if adding an IDENTITY field is allowed. The individual statements would be executed in the order they appear in, which would allow `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY identity_field)` to determine the third row inserted.

Comment: You don't need an IDENTITY for that, you can simply add the value. The OP should think of an ordering critera that isn't as arbitrary as the insertion order.

Comment: @MAK what *real* problem are you trying to solve? Ordering by insertion order is a *very* arbitrary decision. Are you trying to do this in order to solve some *other* problem?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I'm not really bothering about ordering of any fields. I just to want to show the specific row whichever i want and without giving an condition for that.

Comment: @MAK what do you mean by "specific row"? What everyone is telling you is that there *is* no "specific" row. If you don't specify any criteria, at best a primary key, you have no "specific row". Databases aren't flat files where talking about line 12345 makes any sense. They are sets of data, identified by their values, some of which are considered keys. If a db file is fragmented, or partitioning is used, the 123456th insertion can go to the 1st file system block even if the 12345th went to the 10th. With RAID, it's will be different disks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, It's okay man. I solved it. Thank you everyone for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ranking functions require an order, and constants are not allowed, but it can be tricked with a function that returns the same value every time.

```
select * from 
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LEFT(employeeName,0)) rn
    from empo
) result
where result.rn = 3
```

This is still a hack, and the order can change after rebuilding the cluster index, or after deleting and inserting new rows (than can go to the page that contained the previously deteled records).

So, it is highly recommended to add an identity column and use that for ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `ORDER BY employeeName` instead:

```
select * from 
(
    select *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY employeeName ASC) rn
    from empo
) result
where result.rn = 3;
```

Based on your sample data, it seems that order is specified by `employeeName` field.

Note that in SQL tables, *there is no inherent row order*. You **always** have to specify at least one table field in an `ORDER BY` clause, if you want to specify row order.

Comment: If i update `employeeName` of `ID = 4` to `Z` then? And +1 for the note.

Comment: The result will be just as arbitrary as the definition of the "third row". Third row according to what criteria? The question is flawed, based on the incorrect assumption that somehow insertion order matters (it doesn't)

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, Hey thank you for your answer. Anyway i have solved it.